# how to write nested string format?

Tags: python

I used below for string formatting in plotly.

```
texttemplate='%{text:.2f}'
```

now I like to set num of digit as a variable so I have to use nested string format like this, it didn't work. Thanks for your help.

```
num_gigit=f(key)
texttemplate='%{text:.{num_digit}f}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I would try to use the `round` function: `texttemplate='%{round(text, num_digit)}'`</s>

**Edit:**
The following works:

```py
texttemplate='%{text:.' + str(num_digit) + 'f}'
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't work, not sure why?

Comment: Do you need to keep the percentage sign and curly brackets for plotly? 

If so: `texttemplate='%{' + str(round(text, num_digit)) + '}'`

Otherwise: `texttemplate=str(round(text, num_digit))'`

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work either, the error would be text is not defined. text is a special character in plotly and it is defined during fig.add_scatter()

Comment: I just thought of another possible solution: `texttemplate='%{text:.' + str(num_digit) + 'f}'`

Comment: Hi Nicolas, yes this latest one (texttemplate='%{text:.' + str(num_digit) + 'f}') works! Thank you so much! Please changed the answer so I can vote

Comment: @roudan Great! Answer changed.